# Counting within a period of time

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe: 
Person A made 5 vacances, the first vacations were from 2015-03-11 to 2015-03-15 and the last vacations from Person A from 2016-02-04 to 2016-02-10.

```
Person   fromDate    toDate
A        2015-03-11  2015-03-15
A        2015-04-17  2015-06-16
A        2015-09-18  2015-10-12
A        2015-12-18  2016-01-02
A        2016-02-04  2016-02-10
B        2015-04-10  2016-04-16
B        2016-12-12  2016-12-20
C        2015-01-02  2015-02-04
C        2015-03-03  2015-03-05
C        2015-04-04  2015-04-07
C        2016-01-03  2016-01-10
C        2016-10-12  2016-10-15
C        2016-11-01  2016-11-05
```

I want to find all persons which made within 365 days at least 5 times vacations. 
In the example above Person A went in 365 day 5 times on vacation. Person C went on 6 vacations but not within 365 days.
The result should be a dataframe like

```
Person   at_least_five_vacations_within_365_days
A          TRUE
B          FALSE
C          FALSE
```

Comment: What is a holiday?

Comment: You can also say vacances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
df <- fread("Person\tfromDate\ttoDate
          A\t2015-03-11\t2015-03-15
          A\t2015-04-17\t2015-06-16
          A\t2015-09-18\t2015-10-12
          A\t2015-12-18\t2016-01-02
          A\t2016-02-04\t2016-02-10
          B\t2015-04-10\t2016-04-16
          B\t2016-12-12\t2016-12-20
          C\t2015-01-02\t2015-02-04
          C\t2015-03-03\t2015-03-05
          C\t2015-04-04\t2015-04-07
          C\t2016-01-03\t2016-01-10
          C\t2016-10-12\t2016-10-15
          C\t2016-11-01\t2016-11-05",header="auto",sep="auto") %>% 
          as.data.frame() %>%
          mutate(fromDate=ymd(fromDate), toDate=ymd(toDate))
```

Setting `number of trips` window:

```
numoftrips <- 5
```

Using `dpylr` & assuming your dates are already sorted by `Person`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Person) %>% 
  mutate(toCompare=lead(toDate,(numoftrips-1))) %>%         # Copy return date of 5th-trip-after as new column
  mutate(within.year=(toCompare-fromDate)<=365) %>%         # Check if difference is less than 365 days
  summarise(at_least_five_vacations_within_365_days=ifelse(sum(within.year,na.rm=T)>0,TRUE,FALSE))  # If taken 5 trips in less than 365 days, return TRUE
```

Output

```
df1
  Person too.many.vacay
1      A           TRUE
2      B          FALSE
3      C          FALSE
```

Comment: If I run your code, I don't get the same output -  the df looks the same like before.

Comment: I added `library(lubridate)`...Did you use my data? Could you show the output of `str(df)` where `df` is your data?

Comment: @ Chi Pak   I used your data and lubridate                                                                                                   
 > str(df)
'data.frame': 13 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Person  : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ fromDate: Date, format: "2015-03-11" "2015-04-17" ...
 $ toDate  : Date, format: "2015-03-15" "2015-06-16" ...

Comment: Ah, my guess is that you need to add `df1 <-` before `df`...then you can print `df1` after running my code...see my edited answer

Comment: Without the assignment `<-`, it will directly print the evaluation but not save the results.

Comment: You can close this question by accepting an answer (check mark to the left). If a better answer shows up in the future, you can re-accept a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. But you should specify the expected output.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Person) %>%
       mutate(diff = toDate - fromDate,instances = n())%>%
       filter (instances >=5 & diff < 356)
```

`df` is just your dataset and instances is the number of visits for person

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45175250/3817004) uses `data.table` to read the data but continues with a `dplyr` approach.

The approach below uses `read_table2()` from the `readr` package but achieves the desired result with a `data.table` "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
n_trips <- 5L
n_days <- 365L
DT[order(Person, fromDate), 
   any(fromDate <= shift(toDate, n_trips - 1L, , "lag") + n_days, na.rm = TRUE), 
   by = Person][]
```

> ```
>    Person    V1
> 1:      A  TRUE
> 2:      B FALSE
> 3:      C FALSE
> ```

#### Explanation

The approach is similar to the accepted answer: The `toDate` is lagged by the required number of trips of the person and then it is checked whether the actual `fromDate` is within the given range of days. The `any()` function is used to determine if there is at least one occurrence for a particular person. The result of shift operations depend on the order of rows. So, the data.table is ordered beforehand.

The OP has requested *to find all persons which made within 365 days at least 5 times vacations* but he hasn't specified exactly how to count the vacations (by start date, by end date, or by a mixture of both?). So, it has been deliberately chosen to check the end date of the 4th previous vacation vs the start date of the actual vacation.

#### Data

```
DT <- readr::read_table2(
"Person   fromDate    toDate
A        2015-03-11  2015-03-15
A        2015-04-17  2015-06-16
A        2015-09-18  2015-10-12
A        2015-12-18  2016-01-02
A        2016-02-04  2016-02-10
B        2015-04-10  2016-04-16
B        2016-12-12  2016-12-20
C        2015-01-02  2015-02-04
C        2015-03-03  2015-03-05
C        2015-04-04  2015-04-07
C        2016-01-03  2016-01-10
C        2016-10-12  2016-10-15
C        2016-11-01  2016-11-05"
)
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
```